# How to describe any|undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
const localAuth = async (callback: () => any) => { 
// not sure the return type of callback, so cast a any type
  const ok = Math.random()
  if (ok > 0.5)
    return callback()
  else {
    return null
}}

localAuth(() => null).then(val => { 
  console.log(val.mayNotExist) // doesn't complain, but val maybe null!
})
```

The typescript code is as above, because the return type of callback is not sure, so I assigned it a any type, but apparently any type swallows the 'null path', how to change the code to not miss the null possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly define the return type of your localAuth function to be a union of your callback type and null.

```
type anyFunction = () => any;

const localAuth = async (callback: anyFunction): Promise<null|anyFunction> => {
    const ok = Math.random()
    if (ok > 0.5)
        return callback()
    else {
        return null;
    }
};

localAuth(() => null).then(val => {

    console.log(val.arguments) // complains because val may be null

    if (val) {
        console.log(val.arguments) // doesn't complain, because you've checked
    }
    
});
```

This way, you will get the `Object is possibly 'null'` issue from the typescript compiler for your `val.mayNotExist` example, as expected.

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgdiAYgVzgY2ASwPZygXigAoBKAgPlgQG4AoWtXAZ2CgBts0Y2BBZYABYFYTEOmJc2bAEYw0AawBcxMvkrwQJZQAUATtgC2mJhAA8cZFIA+GlOiy5KaqAG9aUD1EZwWUbPOEAWRhBADpdeAATQ1J3T0wAM2J-KEoABlCAVhI4z09dCGBkXTxJGTl5WLyINhNXXLyoAqKSqAspOjyAX1ouuloOST5BIlIKNss2ElDBCDgiADducbcG7yZsNghQjgBzRe5QmF1d5AM54CYyAHprr0MwNhhMHyhpCC5kOqW2KAMYEBvaDtNj0PKJYg-MhuRqedabbZ7A5sI4nM4XK5QW5QaIQJhwADkrEYBkezzgABogZ86iBsMgCQtoGgBB95BBIg0enleiRqEA) so you can see it in action

**Edit 1:**

To answer your comment, you can use type aliases.

```
const localAuth = async <T>(callback: () => T): Promise<null | T> => {
    const ok = Math.random()
    if (ok > 0.5)
        return callback()
    else {
        return null;
    }
};

localAuth(() => null).then(val => {

    // val is type null
    
});

localAuth(() => '').then(val => {

    // val is type (string | null)
    
});
```

[Live typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=20&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiYBDOBBArlAFjAvDJCATzGBgB4AVAPgApk44AjJYAawC4ZaBKPamJR5cACgCcQAWwCWEAKbkw6RjAA%20ggbgEBvAFAwDMUJFgg2eGAFkk2AHRikYACZTe%20w9IBm3MzAEAGWwBWHndDQzE5KHQxMCMUZlY2N3C5OHkYPXDwyOjYmCVGAG4wmABfXTKS3QQGDGxaXn4C5TgeW2w5MFoANxRmvVKAeiGYPrgYWRgoIgAHORbGUsqeatqUeqxGvi0YAHI99s7u8YHdYdHTqZn57mgxaTAAczVFtuWy1aA)

[More reading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases)

Comment: This is incorrect, in your first example you are returning `null | anyFunction` but it should return the return value of `anyFunction`. `null|ReturnType<anyFunction>` works but this will make the compiler not complain anymore.